# Orchard CMS - How to access the items in a container?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

It is necessary to get access to the members of the container element, how to implement it, tell me where to look. Zaklyuchaetsya essence in the following: there is a container in which to contain certain elements necessary to realize the possibility of getting the property values of these elements.

Comment: Two types of content created (ContentType_1 and ContentType_2). ContentType_1 contains ContentPart = Container, ContentType_2 contains Contains and ContentPart = Part_x and Title, etc. How do I get from ContentType_1 Part_x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a previous answer I've made:

The actual content items aren't stored on ContainerPart. Instead, each contained item's CommonPart has a Container value that links to the container. You need to use LINQ to locate all ContentItems that have CommonPart.Container equal to your container.

```
int containerId = containerItem.Id;

var containedList = _contentManager
            .Query<CommonPart>()
            .Join<CommonPartRecord>()
            .Where(x => x.Container.Id == containerId)
            .List();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.